# c++ swapping unique_ptr's

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

New to this kind of stuff, probably doing something wrong, but -

I have 3 members

```
std::unique_ptr<Gun> currentWeapon;
std::unique_ptr<Gun> weaponSlotOne;
std::unique_ptr<Gun> weaponSlotTwo;
```

Gun is a base class that has other derived classes such as `Pistol` and `SMG`.

What i'm doing is setting `weaponSlotOne` and `weaponSlotTwo` to two different guns, then setting `currentWeapon` to the first weapon.

```
weaponSlotOne.reset(new DevPistol());
weaponSlotTwo.reset(new AutoDevPistol());
currentWeapon = std::move(weaponSlotOne);
```

and i have a `switchWeapons` method, that does this:

```
void Player::switchWeapons() {
    if(currentWeapon == weaponSlotOne) {
        currentWeapon = std::move(weaponSlotTwo);
    }
    else {
        currentWeapon = std::move(weaponSlotOne);
    }
}
```

which seems to destroy/deallocate both guns for some reason. i'm not quite sure what's going wrong.

Comment: `unique_ptr` doesn't make sense in this case

Comment: Perhaps: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that after calling `std::move` on an object, the object is in an indeterminate state, and you can't safely do anything with the object other than destroy it or assign to it.

In your case, after doing `currentWeapon = std::move(weaponSlotOne);`, `weaponSlotOne` is indeterminate, so when you test `currentWeapon == weaponSlotOne` you might get any result.  Probably, this will be false (`weaponSlotOne` will be null), so you'll just copy it to `currentWeapon`, dropping whatever was there (deleting it).

The question is, what are you trying to do?  If you want two weapons, and want to keep track of which one is current, it might make more sense to do:

```
std::unique_ptr<Gun> *currentWeapon;
std::unique_ptr<Gun> weaponSlotOne;
std::unique_ptr<Gun> weaponSlotTwo;

weaponSlotOne.reset(new DevPistol());
weaponSlotTwo.reset(new AutoDevPistol());
currentWeapon = &weaponSlotOne;

void Player::switchWeapons() {
    if(currentWeapon == &weaponSlotOne) {
        currentWeapon = &weaponSlotTwo;
    }
    else {
        currentWeapon = &weaponSlotOne;
    }
}
```

Or even more simply:

```
std::unique_ptr<Gun> weaponSlot[2];
int currentWeapon = 0;

void Player::switchWeapons() {
    currentWeapon ^= 1;
}
```

Comment: I'll upvote this, but i've solved it by using swap, and changing the members to `currentWeapon` and `storedWeapon`. I think it's doing what i've wanted it to, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

In general, after moving from an object the moved-from object is in a valid but unspecified state.  This means that you can only safely call those functions on the moved-from object which have no preconditions.  For example destruction typically has no precondition.  Typically neither does assigning to an object.  And typically neither do const observers such as equality comparison with a non-moved from value.

In the case of `std::unique_ptr`, you can safely compare a moved-from value.  But also note that `unique_ptr` has *unique ownership semantics*.  I.e. two non-null `unique_ptr`s should never compare equal, because if they did, they would *own the same pointer*, and thus be in violation of the basic tenant of `unique_ptr`.  But it often makes sense to compare `unique_ptr` with `nullptr` to find out if it owns a non-null pointer:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>

int
main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(3));
    auto p2 = std::move(p);
    assert(p == nullptr); // perfectly legal & practical use of moved-from value
}
```

I suspect the problem with your code is/was that you were mistakenly expecting copy semantics from the `unique_ptr` move assignment: i.e. that the source of the assignment would be left unchanged.  However from my code snippet above it can be shown that the moved-from `unique_ptr` will be reliably left equal to `nullptr`.  There simply is no other way to implement the operation while still satisfying all `unique_ptr` specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever makes it to this post. You can use the std::swap on shared or unique pointer.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/swap/

edit: 
try to avoid code like:

```
weaponSlotOne.reset(new DevPistol());
```

It can cause memory leaks. Better would be:

```
weaponSlotOne = std::make_unique<DevPistol>();
```